# Is it possible to have different price and currency per product and per store view?

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, price, store-view, currency

I have setup multi-site in Magento. I have one Website with two Stores and one storeView per Store.

StoreA is in GBP, StoreB is in Euros. I have productA which I would like to sell for £99.99 from StoreA but I would also like to sell ProductA from StoreB for €99.99 which is a custom price not a conversion rate.

I have tried changing the scope in Manage products page (Admin) but it still displays GBP not matter which storeView I have selected.

I'd be grateful if anyone could explain to me how I can achieve this relatively simple task that appears to be having me in a bit of bother....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about store view with code of currency like EUR / USD and keep language for website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set different prices for different store views and currencies (custom price not a conversion rate) with Advanced Pricing extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-pricing-3001.html

Comment: I think the above extension is the way to go as will need to be able to switch stores from the frontend and have the custom prices shown in different currencies. I was considering this extension as it does exactly what I need and more...

Answer (score 8):

First of all you can't have different prices for stores but only for websites (unless you use one of the custom extensions which extends this functionality). This also has to be enabled `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price`.

Then you can't show different currencies in admin, only at the frontend.

So what you shall do is to create 2 websites, set different currencies for both and in admin enter both prices in base currency using conversion rate (e.g. £99.99 for WbsiteA and £84.64 for WebsiteB. At the frontend £84.64 will be converted into €99.99).

Comment: Now this is awkward. We actually submited the same answer in the same second  :) (2013-06-01 20:39:44Z). Since your answer appears above when I order by 'oldest' I will delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the base currency per store view, just enable the selector by adding this to your favourite system.xml testen in magento 1.9

```
     <sections>
        <currency module="directory">
            <groups>
                <options >
                    <fields>
                        <base>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </base>
                    </fields>
                </options>
            </groups>
        </currency>
    </sections>
</config>
```