# Custom price attribute values not appearing in database

Tags: price, ce-1.9.0.1, database, table

I created 2 custom price attributes as shown in the screenshot.
[image: mulcurr]

I've entered some values. I want that to be reflected in database. Here is the screen shot of the table which contains Price[USD] value.
[image: table]

The values for Price[INR] and Price[EUR] isn't getting reflected, it is showing `NULL` value. How to correct it?

Comment: are you sure that 76 and 120 are the ids of your attributes? Check the eav_attribute table to see the correct ids. Or maybe you didn't add the attributes with tyoe `decimal` and they are shown in a different table. If you see the values in the admin then for sure they are in the db.

Comment: Well, the attribute 76 is pointing to special_price and attribute 120 is pointing to msrp. Where are price[INR] and price[EUR] are stored?

Comment: Got it. The attribute 134 and 135 are pointing to Price[INR] and price[EUR]. But in which table are they stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query

```
Select * From eav_attribute where attribute_code IN ('code for price INR', 'code for price EURO')
```

This should result in 2 rows. Look at the column `backend_type`. It will tell you what type is that attribute.
If the value is `static` then the value should be stored in `catalog_product_entity`, but I doubt that this is the case for you.

for any other value, look in the table `catalog_product_entity_{value here}`.

<strike>By the looks of the values you have in the screenshot I can say that their type is `int`. So look in `catalog_product_entity_int`.</strike>  
Based on the comments...so your type is `varchar`

Run this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE 
    entity_id = 1 AND
    attribute_id IN (134, 135)
```

If I'm right, then you should change the attribute type to decimal so it can be stored as the rest of the prices.

Comment: back-end type says varchar in case of me, so I'm trying catalog_product_entity_varchar table

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. Varchar then. I will update the answer.

Comment: So I'll change varchar to decimal, and hope that the values will appear in catalog_product_entity_decimal

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I decided not to change the values. Let the types be varchar. And I've 1 more requirement. I can do like this for multiple products. If I select any other currency other than default USD, then the corresponding values should be reflected in front end. I don't want magento to convert them to other values based on webserviceex rates. How to do that?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. This is a totally different issue. There are a lot of questions like this on this website. See if the answers for any one of them fits your needs.

Comment: Can you provide me links for such questions? or try to provide solutions for this requirement? It is urgent for my client.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. This is the first one it poped up: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/4339/146. Use the search of this website, or even google to find other answers and extensions.

Comment: That link says to install advanced pricing extension which isn't free. My client doesn't want to pay for that extension. Is there any module or extension which can do it? Is it possible to disable currency conversion in magento?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15625/discussion-between-ajay-kulkarni-and-marius).